# How to sort images by a dominant color, or the background color

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have 8000 images and essentially need to delete any photo that has a white background. I'm hoping to find a way I can sort all of these images by the dominant color (which would hopefully be white), or by the background colour, lets say the top left pixel.

Can this be achieved with imagemagick?

Comment: technically speaking white and black are no colours btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just compute the percentage of white pixels in the image using ImageMagick?

```
convert image -fuzz XX% -fill white -opaque white -fill black +opaque white -scale 1x1 -format "%[fx:100*mean]\n" info:
```

The result will be the percentage of white in your image.

Where XX% is the percent tolerance for how close to white you want to consider as white. If you want only pure white, then use 0%. If you want to include near white, then increase XX%.

PS  Sorry @emcconville, we must have posted about the same time. Mostly the same solution, but yours is more thorough regarding sorting.

Comment: This is a better solution then my proposed "calculate mean", as it can be leveraged for none-white backgrounds. Both the `fuzz` and color values can be adjusted as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the mean pixel value, sort, and pipe to other utilities.

```
for f in *.jpg
do
  identify -format '%[mean] %f\n' "$f"
done | sort -r | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

- The `identify -format '%[mean] %f\n' "$f"` will calculate the average pixel values (numbers increase as they approach white). For example...

  ```
  14524.3 output0.jpg
  64246.8 output1.jpg
  34612.2 output2.jpg
  ```
- Pipe to `sort -r` to reverse sort.

  ```
  64246.8 output1.jpg
  34612.2 output2.jpg
  14524.3 output0.jpg
  ```
- And pipe to `cut -d ' ' -f 2` to drop calculated mean.

  ```
  output1.jpg
  output2.jpg
  output0.jpg
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From what I found doing a 1 minute web research (actually your job) this is possible.

Reduce the number of colours for speedup (if needed)
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#colors

Then create a histogram to get the colour frequencies
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#histogram

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#extract

Then sort the output by the frequency of the most dominant colour

More info can be found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/576949/getting-the-predominant-colour-in-an-image