# How can I identify images with a dominant color of white but ignoring the alpha channel in the calculation?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to do [exactly this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114818/how-to-sort-images-by-a-dominant-color-or-the-background-color). I need to identify images with a dominant color of white.

I've tried the answer in the question I referenced above:

```
magick image -fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque white -fill black +opaque white -scale 1x1 -format "%[fx:100*mean]\n" info:
```

However my images have an alpha channel and it seems that is being taken into consideration during the calculation because the result I'm getting is `25` despite the image being pure white with transparency.

**Here are a couple example images** (Note, they will look invisible since it's on a white background, but the images are in-fact there):

[image: Transparent Image 1]
[image: Transparent Image 2]
[image: Transparent Image 3]

Can someone help me identify white images while ignoring transparency in the mean calculation?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the alpha channel off and use 1x1! (note the ! mark) in Imagemagick.

```
magick white.png -alpha off -fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque white -fill black +opaque white -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:100*mean]\n" info:

91.9187
```

or

```
magick white.png -alpha off -fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque white -fill black +opaque white -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:100*u]\n" info:

91.9187
```

I note that your white image has black in the base rgb image and also in the alpha channel.  Perhaps you should make the base image perfectly white.

```
magick white.png -background white -alpha background -scale 1x1! -alpha off -format "%[fx:100*mean]\n" info:

99.9999
```